# Very low microphone volume on bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm trying to use my Marshall Major IV as a headset, but for some reason the volume is very low. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. The headset is connected through bluetooth. I tried several things now, but nothing seems to change the microphone volume.

Bluetooth profiles `HSP/HFP` and `A2PD Sink` worked out of the box, and I'm able to switch between them without any problem. I use the `HSP/HFP` profile when trying to use the microphone.

In system settings, despite microphone volume being set to the max, when I'm talking it only detects a [very low sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgLRS.png).

I searched around for solutions and I increased the [Headphone Mic Boost to the maximum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQpN8.png) in `alsamixer`. This didn't improve the microphone volume.

I installed `pauvcontrol` and indeed it shows that [the internal microphone works as expected, while the headset microphone doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMcFd.png). Changing the microphone volume slider does nothing. Even if I set it to 0 (no volume), the headset still detects sounds as being low.

I also tried `blueman`, but I couldn't find anything useful there.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several months living with this problem, I was finally able to solve it.

The solution is switching Ubuntu's audio server. By default it uses Pulseaudio, but we will replace it with Pipewire. Pipewire supports more bluetooth profiles than Pulseaudio, which should fix most bluetooth audio issues on Ubuntu.

Follow the instructions on [this medium post](https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0) to switch to Pipewire audio server.

Take care that the double dash is not correctly formatted on that site. Whenever you see something like this:

```
systemctl — user daemon-reload
```

You must replace it with:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
```